# What is the name of a distribution within $[a, b]$ but with a sloped straight line density?

Tags: distributions

What is the name of a distribution such that it looks like uniform distribution on $[a, b]$,
but the density is not a horizontal line, but a line with a certain slope.

Comment: Why not call it a trapezoidal distribution? That's the shape we see.

Answer (score 10):

**A distribution with a linear PDF can be considered a special case of a (truncated) Pareto distribution, Beta distribution, or power distribution.**  Only particular values of the parameters in these distribution families will give a linear PDF, of course.

---

Among other things, such a distribution is a [truncated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_distribution) **Generalized Pareto Distribution.**  The [Wikipedia parameterization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Pareto_distribution) of the PDF (for the case where the endpoints $a$ and $b$ are finite, as they must be for a linear graph) can be expressed in terms of the basic function

$$f(x; \eta) = (1 - \eta x)^{1/\eta - 1}$$

for $0\le x \le 1/\eta$.  (This can then be rescaled by $\sigma\ne 0$ and shifted by $\mu$ to obtain the most general form.  Here I have set $\eta = -\xi$ which will be a *positive* number.)

Evidently this function is linear in $x$ if and only if $1/\eta - 1=1$; that is, $\eta = 1/2$ (and so $\xi=-1/2$).  Its graph equals zero at the endpoint $x=1/\eta = 2$.  By *truncating* it, though, we would obtain the general form stated in the question.

---

The same thing can be obtained by truncating a generalized [**Beta Distribution**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution).  Its PDF is proportional to

$$x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}$$

for $0\le x \le 1$, whence the Beta$(2,1)$ and Beta$(1,2)$ distributions are linear.  As with the Pareto$(\xi=-1/2)$ distribution, the graphs of these PDFs are zero at one endpoint.  The general linear PDF described in question is obtained in the same way via truncation, rescaling, and shifting.

---

Finally, [*Mathematica*](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerDistribution.html) defines a "**power distribution**" as one having a PDF proportional to

$$f(x; k, a) = x^{a-1}$$

for $0 \le x \le 1/k$.  The case $a=2$ gives a linear PDF, identical to Beta$(2,1)$.  Rescaling it by $k$ and recentering it with a parameter $\mu$, and (once again) truncating it will yield the general PDF described in the question.

Comment: The power/Beta$(\alpha, 1)$ distributions can also be characterized as "log exponential" distributions: see [this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/115682). For instance, when $X$ has an Exponential (aka Gamma$(1,1)$) distribution, then $(1/\sqrt{e})^X=\exp(-X/2)$ has a Beta$(2,1)$ distribution with linear density rising from $0$ at $x=0$ to $2$ at $x=1$.  Adding a constant to $X$ rescales it and adding a constant to the entire result shifts it.  Truncating that on the left gives the general form requested in the question.

Answer (score 7):

It might be the [triangular distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution). The general triangular distribution with support $[a,b]$ has 1 parameter $c\in[a,b]$ corresponding to the mode. When $c=a$ or $c=b$, the p.d.f. is a straight line segment.

Comment: This distribution bears its name because the density has a *triangular* shape, not that of a line segment of fixed slope!

Comment: @whuber That is correct. As I mentioned, the pdf is shaped as a straight line when c=a or c=b (the interval boundaries). It is triangular when c is not equal to a or b. Is this not correct?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think your statement is correct. On the other hand, the limitation is that the triangular distribution have 0 density at least one of the ends (i.e., a or b). That is, it cannot be used to describe a density function where the density on the edges are non-zero. Let me know if I missed anything

Comment: It is true that any triangular distribution with its mode at one end of the range has a linear density. However, the general linear density doesn't necessarily have $f(x)=0$ as either end. Think instead of a mixture of a mode-at-one-end triangular density with a uniform (making, in effect, a trapezoid with the two parallel sides parallel to the y-axis). There's some discussion of the issue [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/113759/how-to-test-if-some-data-points-is-drawn-from-a-distribution-with-linear-pdf)